# C# - Windows Forms: Different values for Cursor.Current in main thread and another thread

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to examine the cursor's mode at different times when my program is running.
I am doing this by creating a thread, that when needed will let me know what is the current state of the cursor. For some reason, I get different outputs on the main thread and the new thread created.

I did a little experiment with the **Cursor** class inside of Windows Forms app.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Cursor = Cursors.AppStarting;
        new System.Threading.Thread(delegate()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine(Cursor.Current);
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
            }
        }).Start();
    }
}
```

So basically when my cursor is on the **AppStarting** mode, so the `Cursor.Current` should be equal to `Cursors.AppStarting` but for some reason, The value it prints is **WaitCursor** (which basically means it is equal to `Cursors.WaitCursor`).
Anybody knows why?
Thank you in advance.

Edit: Thanks to everyone who commented and helped me out.

Comment: Internally it using GetCursor winapi function... Which returns cursor for current thread...

Comment: `BeginInvoke(delegate { Console.WriteLine(Cursor.Current); });` -- That Thread needs to be a Background Thread. You have a Foreground Thread that keeps running after the Form is closed

Comment: That code doesn't even compile ...

Comment: @Fildor putting this into `class Form1:Form` and fixing obvious typo and it compiles

Comment: @Selvin Yes, OP should do that.

Comment: You need to do everything related to the UI on the UI thread, that should include the Cursor. You should probably create a timer that runs on the UI thread and prints out the current cursor.  Or even better, Create a `SetCursor`-method and use this everywhere, this should give you a place to log changes and place breakpoints.

Comment: `private Cursor GetCursor() => IsHandleCreated ? InvokeRequired ? (Cursor)Invoke((Func<Cursor>)GetCursor) : Cursor.Current : null;` ... and then use `GetCursor()`

Comment: @Selvin You don't need to check either `IsHandleCreated` or `InvokeRequired` (you also already know that it's required). See my first comment -- When the Handle is not created, the Cursor is just `WaitCursor`

Comment: @Jimi ...  Invoke obviously doesn't work without handle

Comment: @Selvin I didn't use `Invoke()`... You only get an usable result after the handle has been created, otherwise, as mentioned, you get `WaitCursor` -- You can simply test it, adding the required delay

Comment: same story with `BeginInvoke` ... call `BeginInvoke` without handle created and you will get `InvalidOperationException`

Comment: `IsHandleCreated` is only redundant with `InvokeRequired` (just tested)

Comment: And nobody talks about the tight loop?

Comment: @Fildor I've tested in LinqPAD... looks fine ... with Invoke it will only go so fast as messageloop

Comment: Winforms uses the [GetCursor() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcursor) to retrieve the current cursor.  Note how the article specifically warns about threads (without explicitly stating the fact that the current cursor behaves like a ThreadStatic property) and what you need to do to retrieve the global cursor.  http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetCursorInfo.html

Comment: @Fildor what do you mean by that?

Comment: that you have almost `while(true) { }` without any delay

Comment: @Selvin Yes, but that Thread (assuming this code is actually real stuff you do) needs a delay. And it doesn't really need to be set in the Constructor of a Form. So you would start it in `OnhandleCreated()` or in `OnLoad()` or in `OnShown()` or whatever. Not in the Constructor, of course -- The Problem is the use of `Invoke()`, not the handle creation (which can also be forced, if needed) -- As mentioned, this is also a Foreground Thread. So it's all wrong, as it is

Comment: @Nexospex A loop that runs infinitely without much to do. Which means it will loop _fast_ and forever. Which is rarely a good idea.

Comment: @Selvin oh, I did have a delay, I do not know why I did not type that in the question. Regardless, this is just an experiment, not a piece of code from a real App

Comment: @HansPassant How are there multiple cursors? I can control multiple cursors?

Comment: You must have seen this before.  You can have multiple windows on your desktop, each owned by its own process and thread.  And when one of them displays, say, an hourglass cursor then you can switch to another window and the cursor changes.  So yes, the current cursor is a thread-specific property in Windows.  What "control" might mean is not obvious, it is the window that determines what the cursor looks like.  You don't want to retrieve the current cursor of a thread that has no windows created at all.  Don't use it as an alternative for a variable in your program.

Comment: @JonasH Let's say I want to check every couple of seconds whether or not the cursor is inside the form window, how can I do that on the UI thread without it making my window freeze?

Comment: if "every couple second" then you may use UI thread (even every 1 second) ... just use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` ... it just send WM_TIMER on message loop on UI thread and execute your method in WinProc ....(well, depends what you are doing based on `Cursor.Current` ... but you can allways check and run another thread)

Comment: Checking if the mouse is inside a form should take on the order of *microseconds*. This is not in any way noticeable and will not make your window freeze, unless you are doing it *many* times each second. Ofc. you also have MouseEnter/Leave events that should allow you to only do things when the mouseOver state is changed.

Comment: Anyway, it seems like xy problem ... Why you wana do something based on your window Cursor state ?

Comment: @Selvin I am doing a project that simulates a Remote Control, so I wanted to learn about this Cursor class. (ofc i am working with the user32.dll too)

Comment: like RDP (or desktop sharing in Teams) ? or you just wana call some methods remotely? ... if second then just do nice separation UI from logic and build webservice (whatever technology) ... if first then maybe capturing WM_XXX messages is better idea (on client and posting them to server then send image of window to client)

Comment: @Selvin I mean the first option, Why would capturing the messages would be better than using the WinApi?
And what does your second option mean? like what calling methods remotely is?

Comment: @Selvin Hey selvin, I hope you could answer one more question for me.
is the Timer class of the System.Windows.Forms working on the same thread as the UI (is that the meaning by a single-threaded). and if you see this thank you for your comments

Comment: Yes it is... But remember `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` and NOT `System.Threading.Timer` NOR `System.Timers.Timer`... So watch out of used `using`

Comment: And remember to not do a lot a job there, since it is on UI thread it will block it

Answer (score 0):

Your post states an unreliable assumption:

> So basically when my cursor is on the AppStarting mode, so the Cursor.Current should be equal to Cursors.AppStarting...

Then you code it in your `Form1` this way:

```
this.Cursor = Cursors.AppStarting;
```

The problem is that value of `Cursor.Current` doesn't (necessarily) come from `this.Cursor`. *It comes from the `Control` that it's hovered over (and is different for NC vs Client rectangles).*

You can prove this by moving the cursor, then iterating the control tree to compare the static value of `Cursor.Current` to that of the `Cursor` properties of the controls themselves. Watch the **first two** lines in particular as the cursor is moved:

[image: location dependency]

```
private void displayCursors()
{
    richTextBoxCursors.Clear();
    richTextBoxCursors.SelectionColor = Color.Navy;
    richTextBoxCursors.AppendText($"Cursor : {Cursor.Current} {Environment.NewLine}");
    IterateControlTree(this, (control) => localAddEntry(control));

    void localAddEntry(Control control)
    {
        if (!(control is RichTextBox)) // Exempt the RichTextBox
        {
            var isDefault = control.Cursor.Equals(Cursors.Default);
            Color color = isDefault ? Color.Green : Color.Red;
            richTextBoxCursors.SelectionColor = color;
            richTextBoxCursors.AppendText($"{control.Name} : {control.Cursor} {Environment.NewLine}");
        }
    }
}
```

---

Basically, I read Selvin's excellent observation and agreed this "might" be an [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). The above explains **"different values for Cursor.Current in main thread and another thread..."** only it's not a *thread* dependency holding sway here.

What alternative is there to the non-UI thread you now have coded?

In the course of trying to reproduce your problem, I made a [full solution](https://github.com/IVSoftware/cursor-extravaganza.git) that iterates the control tree and attaches a handler to every control for the `CursorChanged` event. This "almost" eliminates the need to do continuous polling except that when the cursor changes as a result of the `UseWaitCursor` property this event doesn't fire. This necessitates some measured polling (~100 ms) on the state of `Cursor.Current` as well.

---

**Other observations (see extended readme documentation on [repo](https://github.com/IVSoftware/cursor-extravaganza.git))**

[image: screenshot]

---

*Iterating the control tree of Form*

```
internal void IterateControlTree(Control control, Action<Control> fx)
{
    fx(control);
    foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
    {
        IterateControlTree(child, fx);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/cursor-extravaganza) this minimal sample.